# how to move a rectangle over a image in matlab

Tags: matlab

i am new to matlab

now i am studying about optic disc localization

here my first step is to create two feature maps 
secondly i have to create a rectangle and move the rectangle from left to right in first feature  map and the width  is 30 and height of the rectangle is image height

and in the second feature map i have move the rectangle for top to bottom

**third step is at each position of the rectangle i have to calculate the sum and plot the sum value and obtain two graphs**

now  i have used nlfilter  which has the width and dimension as that of the rectangle for calculation but i can't get the answer please help me and this is my code

---

```
final2=edgediff./eror;
figure,image((final2));
title('Feature MAP 1');
func = @(x) sum(x(:));
B = nlfilter(final2,[30 600],func);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're studying optic disc localization I think what you're doing is really two convolutions separately on the horizontal and vertical directions.  In fact, the fact that you are using a linear function `sum` shows that you don't need the non-linear filter function `nlfilter`.  Consider using `conv2` with `ones(ncols, nrows)` instead.

Something like this:

```
[width, height] = size(featureMap1);
box = ones(30, height);
smoothFeatureMap1 = conv2(featureMap1, box, 'same');
```

Repeat but with `box = ones(width, 30)` to get `smoothFeatureMap2`.

Then you can just add the two smooth feature maps together.

However to be honest I think maybe what you want is just the result of a single 2D convolution, not the sum of two other ones.  It's hard to tell for sure from the question.  Particularly I have no idea what you want to graph in your two graphs.  (I'll try to update this answer if you make the question more clear).

Comment: @pushparavi You can either edit your question to add more information or add a comment. It is not proper to add more about your question to an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [imrect](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/imrect.html) from the Image Processing Toolbox to place a rectangle and obtain its coordinates:

```
H = imrect(axes, position);
```